# Get underlying/derived type of enum?

Tags: c#

How can you get the underlying/derived Type(byte, short, int, etc) of an enum?

Comment: @ChrisF: Looking for the Type not the Value.

Comment: My apologies. I misread the other title. If I could take back the close vote I would. Deleted auto inserted comment.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are looking for `Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType)`;

Sample from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getunderlyingtype.aspx):

```
static object GetAsUnderlyingType(Enum enval)
{
    Type entype = enval.GetType();

    Type undertype = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(entype);

    return Convert.ChangeType(enval, undertype);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
using System;

class Program
{
    enum IntEnum : int { A }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var intEnum = IntEnum.A;

        Console.WriteLine(intEnum.GetType().GetEnumUnderlyingType());

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }       
}
```