# C# BaseType of enum

Tags: c#, types, enums

I have a `enum Color`, it may derive from `long` or `byte` or `int`, and I want to know what type does it really derive from, `long` or `byte` or `int`? In the process, I have met 2 problems.

First, the `Color` is defined like below:

```
enum Color : long
{
    red = 1,
    black = 2,
    blue = 3
}
```

### Problem 1

I write the code below to do such things:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Color));    // ConsoleApp7.Color
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Color).BaseType);    // System.Enum
```

At this moment, I met my first problem: it's curious that `typeof(Color).BaseType` is `System.Enum`, because `Color` is a `enum` type.

**So I'm wondering that whether you defining a `enum` type like `enum Enum1 { ... }`, it actually means that: `class Enum1 : enum { ... }`?**

### Problem 2

Based on problem 1, if I want to get its **real** base type, I need to write:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Color).BaseType.BaseType);
```

Its output is `System.ValueType`, we know that `int`, `byte` and `long` all are `System.ValueType`, how can I get the keyword **long**?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get underlying/derived type of enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305627/get-underlying-derived-type-of-enum)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want an **Underlying** type, not **Base** type:

```
var underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(ConsoleColor))
```

Also note that any *specific* enum (like your `Color`) is a value type and base type of `System.Enum` is `System.ValueType` (despite the fact that `System.Enum` is a reference type). That's why your `typeof(Color).BaseType.BaseType` equals `System.ValueType`